# How to calculate poker outs in Hold'em?

Tags: math, heuristics, poker

I'm making poker hand analysis program just for fun and already done hand evaluator, that determines what kind of hand it is (pair, straight, etc).

But now I'm stuck doing the calculation of outs based on 5 (flop) and 6 (turn) cards. So I need to calculate the number of cards for each combo (pair, straight, etc), that aren't in hand yet, but are possible to be dealt.

What would be the possible approach for this? Is it even possible to make without sort of monte-karlo?

Comment: You do not ask to create algorithms here.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, but for the point on doing this, because i have no ideas at all.

Comment: see http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/32/3816 and http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/4429/3816 for starters

Comment: Why bother with Monte Carlo? There's only 900 possible outcomes...just run them all and tabulate the results.